# When to use phrase in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm trying to learn more about DCGs in Prolog and while reading through different sources, I noticed that in some cases phrase wasn't being used ?

From the Learn Prolog Now website, it presents this example:

```
s   -->  np,vp. 
np  -->  det,n. 
vp  -->  v,np. 
vp  -->  v. 
det -->  [the]. 
det -->  [a]. 
n   -->  [woman]. 
n   -->  [man]. 
v   -->  [shoots].
```

They then use the query `s(X,[])` to generate all the sentences in the grammar.
I tried `phrase(s,L)` and it also generates all the sentences described by the grammar.

What's the difference in using `s(X,[])` and `phrase(s,L)`? When should phrase be used?

Comment: You mean `s(X, [])` not `s([], X)`. The query `s([], X)` will fail. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammar rules should always be accessed using the `phrase/2-3` predicates. When the first argument is instantiated, the Prolog compiler should be expected to convert the `phrase/2-3` call to a call to the predicate generated by the compilation of called grammar rule. Thus, there should be no overhead by using the `phrase/2-3` predicates.

Comment: Is it bad practice to use `s(X,[])`, `np([a,woman],[])` and other queries of the same form ? If so why would these kinds of practices be used in learning materials ?

Comment: Bad habits from the early days of Prolog, I assume.

Comment: It's bad advice on the part of the Learning Prolog Now! website. They don't even mention `phrase/2-3`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, SWI-Prolog performs type checking (arguments must proper lists), then exhibits a performance penalty when using phrase/3.

Also, to allow for using a DCG and perform 'state threading', that is handing off to hidden parameters the state propagation, a [call_dcg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_dcg/3)/3 has been introduced.

But for normal usage - lexical parsing and generation - phrase is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but SWI-Prolog type checking in this case is quite light. In recent versions, it just checks that the second and third arguments are either variables or have a list functor.